# Using Firebase with Express: app.post() not working with existing files under the public folder

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am currently learning express.js and building a dynamic website with firebase. The website is really simple, it takes two numbers from user input and sends back the sum. I have one test.html in the public folder, which contains the html form, inputs, and submit button. In index.js in the functions folder I specified the app.post method, and in firebase.json in my project folder the rewrite properties is the same as the tutorial from firebase: [Use a web framework](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#use_a_web_framework).

/public/test.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>

    <form action="/test" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="Enter your first number">
        <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Enter your second number">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

/functions/index.js:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/test", (req, res) => {
    res.send("The answer is " + (Number(req.body.num1) + Number(req.body.num2)));
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

/firebase.json:

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    ......
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "**",
      "function": "app"
    } ]
  }
  ......
}
```

When I open the page, the form, boxes, and submit button appear just as specified in the test.html file. I expect that when I enter two numbers in the input boxes the website would return their sum, as specified in index.js. However, when I click the submit button, nothing happens.

Comment: Pretty sure `/test` will be rewritten to `/test.html` because static files take priority.

Comment: @samthecodingman Then how can I make sure that test.html is loaded at first, and the app.post() method is executed when I enter the inputs?

Comment: It seems impossible that _"nothing happens"_. It's a regular HTML form with no JavaScript intervention so it should simply submit. You can see what's going on at a network level using your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel.

Comment: @samthecodingman that would only match a request for `/test.html` but OP is posting to `/test`. That being said, it's probably a good idea to prefix API routes with something like `/api`

Comment: @Phil Firebase Hosting [cleans URLs by default](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#control_html_extensions) (by redirecting `.html`). So `/test` and `/test.html` are considered equivalent. If OP changed their route in express to something else or changed `cleanUrls` to `false`, it should work as they expect.

Comment: @samthecodingman interesting, didn't know about that feature but is `true` the default? I couldn't see that mentioned anywhere